# How to send a post?

Tags: java, post, selenium

How to send a post using Java?

I am using selenium and java to run some automated tests against a web application.
One part of my java code, I would like to send a http post request with an post data email to a php page.

the post data should look like this "emails=username@domain.com"

For some reason, I can't seem to get it to work, I feel the code is correct, but figured maybe some more eyes look at it, and can help me determine the issue

It compiles and runs, but it does not seem to be sending the post data to the php file, is what it looks like.

So is there a way to output what it is exactly sending to the php file?

And also, is there a way to return a message from a server? like "Invalid Request" or Success or something.

And I'm not sure what it is missing in the code, if I am missing anything as far as completing a proper POST. 
:

```
package drtest;

//for selenium each part of the test
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

// classes for selenium to work properly in java
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

//java .net libraries
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.*;

//selenium java integration
public class devicereplication extends SeleneseTestBase {
       public Selenium selenium;

       @BeforeMethod // this part of the code points to selenium server and launches the web browser
       public void beforeMethod() {
             selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "firefox",
                           "https://example.com");
             selenium.start();
       }


       @Test // this part of the code is the actual test being run in both java and selenium
       public void testme() {

        //login steps
        selenium.open("/dashboard/login/");
        selenium.click("id=email");
        selenium.type("id=email", "username@domain.com");
        selenium.type("id=pass", "strongpassword");
        selenium.click("id=submitInfo");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

        // deploy agent steps
        selenium.open("/dashboard/");
        selenium.click("link=Deployment");
        selenium.click("link=Deploy Agents");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("90000");

        try {

        int userCount = 5; // how many automation users in the db you are adding a device to.
        int counter = 1;
        String emailDomain = "@domain.com";
        String userName = "username";

        for (;counter <= userCount; counter ++) //this loop adds incremental values to each e-mail/username combo.
        {
        String combinedEmail = (userName+counter+emailDomain); //turns the email name into a string that can be looped.


        String request = "https://examples.com/example/example.php";
        URL url = new URL(request); //requests url

        String param=URLEncoder.encode(combinedEmail, "UTF-8");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        //  connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "example.com");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        //  connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        //  connection.setRequestProperty("X-Request", "JSON");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://example.com/example/example.php"); 
        //  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "344");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);


                  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                  wr.writeBytes(param);
                  wr.flush();
                  wr.close();
                  connection.disconnect();
        }

        } catch(MalformedURLException ex) {
                    System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
                } catch(IOException ex){
                    System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
                } 
}
@AfterMethod
       public void afterMethod() {
             //selenium.stop();
       }

}
```

Comment: _I can't seem to get it to work_ Explain.

Comment: It compiles and runs, but it does not seem to be sending the post data to the php file, is what it looks like.

So is there a way to output what it is exactly sending to the php file?

And also, is there a way to return a message from a server?
like "Invalid Request" or Success or something.

And I'm not sure what it is missing in the code, if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the actual response to get the connection to actually connect.  something like `connection.getResponseCode()`.

also, ditch the DataOutputStream, just use:

```
              OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
              out.write(param.getBytes("UTF-8"));
              out.flush();
              out.close();
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by using .write(param.getBytes("UTF-8"))

I feel like some part is missing before the .write
And I dunno what that function is. Sorry, I'm new to Java not sure what you mean there.

Comment: thanks for your help. You helped me solved the issue, that was essentially it.

Answer (score 0):

You are disconencting the `connection` before doing any validation on response code. Try doing something like this before `disconnect()`

```
int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
if(rc==200){
   //Success
} else if(rc==401) {
   System.out.println("http response code error: "+rc);
} else if(rc==404){
   //Not Found  
}
```

That should complete your test.